# What is AgHost.BackgroundTask as background task in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

When I create a new Windows Phone SIlverlight 8.1 app, there is a background task in the manifest:

```
 <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="AgHost.BackgroundTask">
      <BackgroundTasks>
         <Task Type="systemEvent" />
     </BackgroundTasks>
</Extension>
```

What is it? Is it safe to remove? The only reference I could find is not very helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn642084.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AgHost.exe is the foreground process. This entry point is to allow you to host a background process, if necessary.

Unless you're writing a VoIP application, this should be perfectly safe to remove. However, if you're utilizing one or more background agents for GPS tracking, push notifications, or the likes, this might still be necessary.