# Windows phone 8.1 app crash report . Nothing is there to identify the reason of crash

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have published a `Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight` application to the market. And among many users, some of them are getting (`3 or 4 were reported out of 8000 users`) **app crash issue**.

I checked with the issue on our end and provided all possible steps to prevent the crash. But unfortunately the users are getting the same app crash. *AND THE USERS AND ME ARE EQUALLY WORRIED.!! :(*

When I checked with the dev center crash reports I found the following exception details which I never get on debugging the device

> unknown!{0DFF7A2F-51F8-4DE8-8E37-5E97FAB540C0}_Task_disconnected_while_still_running:_server_task_currentState_=_Active,*targetState*=_Active.
>
> MISSING_DUMP_EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444_unknown.dll!{0DFF7A2F-51F8-4DE8-8E37-5E97FAB540C0}_Task_disconnected_while_still_running:_server_task_currentState_=_Active,*targetState*=_Active.
>
> aghost.exe!{0DFF7A2F-51F8-4DE8-8E37-5E97FAB540C0}_Quiesce_Hang

And I noticed that most users are getting the crash on navigating in to **a page where all phone contacts with images are displaying**. Will it kill the app by any chance?

Can anyone please explain when these above crashes occurs and how can I resolve it ? Since it is not replicated on our end till now.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185201/what-is-aghost-backgroundtask-as-background-task-in-windows-phone-silverlight-8)!

But I do not think that this is your problem. But you could try to delete it, if you can recreate the issue. But it seems the issue is somewhere in this area

aghost.exe!{0DFF7A2F-51F8-4DE8-8E37-5E97FAB540C0}_Quiesce_Hang

> Wiki
>   To Quiesce is to pause or alter a device or application to achieve a consistent state, usually in prepararion for a backup or other maintenance. In software applications that modify information stored on disk, this generally involves flushing any outstanding writes; see buffering. With telecom applications, this generally involves allowing existing callers to finish their call but preventing new calls from initiating.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a background task running in your app maybe it is getting shutdown due to low resources

Comment: Yes . In the Package manifest ,  <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="AgHost.BackgroundTask">
          <BackgroundTasks>
          <Task Type="systemEvent" />
          </BackgroundTasks>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>

Comment: But it is by default and not added by me. If remove it what will happen ?