# Handling the Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Suspending event

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I try to resolve the dreaded `.WindowsPhone.exe!{<ID>}_Quiesce_Hang` hang issue of my WinRT (Windows Phone 8.1) app.

At the moment I have the following handling of the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Suspending` event:

```
    private void App_Suspending(object iSender, SuspendingEventArgs iArgs)
    {
        SuspendingDeferral clsDeferral = null;
        object objLock = new object();

        try
        {
            clsDeferral = iArgs.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            DateTimeOffset clsDeadline = iArgs.SuspendingOperation.Deadline;

            //This task is to ensure that the clsDeferral.Complete() 
            //is called before the deadline.
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(
                async delegate
                {
                    //Reducing the timeout by 1 second just in case.
                    TimeSpan clsTimeout = clsDeadline.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

                    if (clsTimeout.TotalMilliseconds > 100)
                    {
                        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(clsTimeout);
                    }

                    DeferrerComplete(objLock, ref clsDeferral);
                });

            //Here I execute the suspending code i.e. I serializing the app
            //state and save it in files. This may take more than clsTimeout
            //on some devices.
            ...

            //I do not call the Complete method here because the above
            //suspending code is old-fashoin asynchronous i.e. not async but
            //returns before the job is done.
            //DeferrerComplete(objLock, ref clsDeferral);
        }
        catch
        {
            DeferrerComplete(objLock, ref clsDeferral);
        }
    }
```

---

```
    private static void DeferrerComplete(object iLock, ref SuspendingDeferral ioDeferral)
    {
        lock (iLock)
        {
            if (ioDeferral != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    ioDeferral.Complete();
                }
                catch
                {
                }

                ioDeferral = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31871700/1928164) about the `_Quiesce_Hang` problem. I get the idea that it might be related to app storage activity. So my question is: what am I missing? Does my handling of the `Suspending` event look OK?

Comment: I tested your posted code in windows phone 8.1 app with Emulator 8.1, it works fine, may be the problem is with your commented part?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT The commented part is merely serialization and saving files. Obviously it is the commented part that affects the app health reports but this is the idea of the question. I need to be sure that the shown code does protect the user from heavy CPU and IO load in the commented part.